# Why do non-hydrogen atomic orbitals have the same degeneracy structure as hydrogen orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atomic-physics, orbitals

The solutions of the Schrödinger equation for hydrogen are the "electronic orbitals", shown in this picture:

[image]([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital))

They have the following degeneracy structure:

[image]([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital))

It is often said that atoms in other elements simply have more electrons "filling up" the orbitals in increasing order of energy, as required by the Pauli exclusion principle.  This is somewhat confirmed via xray spectroscopy:

[image]([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:XASEdges.svg))

But why would non-hydrogen atoms have the same orbital degeneracy structure as hydrogen, if the actual Hamiltonian is different from one atom to another?

Comment: I suspect that the shell theorem plays a part in why this is a working approximation.

Answer (score 32):

Polyelectronic atoms don't have atomic orbitals - though they are a very useful approximation for describing the properties of polyelectronic atoms.

The 1s, 2s, etc orbitals are solutions for a central potential, and for any smooth monotonic central potential we'll get solutions of this form. The radial part of the orbitals will be different for different central potentials but the angular part is dictated by the spherical symmetry and is the same for all (smooth monotonic) central potentials.

But for any atom with more than two electrons the potential is not centrally symmetric because it includes terms like $1/r_{ij}$ for the interaction between the $i$th and $j$th electrons. This means the hydrogenic orbitals are not solutions.

However because the electrons are delocalised over the whole atom the potential is approximately central. By this I mean that if we take a time average potential the $1/r_{ij}$ terms tend to average out to a central force. In that case we do get hydrogenic type orbital as solutions, but we have to bear in mind that they are approximate solutions. They should be regarded as a useful way of building up the complete electronic structure but they are not themselves real. For example in a lithium atom there is not actually two electrons in a 1s orbital and one in a 2s orbital. There is a single three electron wavefunction that can be approximately decomposed into hydrogenic 1s and 2s orbitals for convenience.

Having said this, for most purposes the hydrogenic orbitals are very good approximations. For example when we are considering atomic spectra we usually describe them as transitions between the hydrogenic orbitals and this works pretty well.

Comment: why with two electrons the potential is still centrally symmetric?

Comment: @Sparkler: suppose you're sitting on electron $i$ looking at electron $j$. From your perspective electron $j$ will spend as much time to the left of the nucleus as to the right of the nucleus, and as much time above the nucleus as below the nucleus. So even though the force due to electron $j$ is in lots of different directions if you take a time average the force vector will point towards the nucleus i.e. on average it is a central force.

Comment: so Li is not actually $\mathrm{1s^2 2s^1}$ but rather $\mathrm{1\square^3}$..?

Comment: @Sparkler: yes, though obviously your notation is not standard. We would normally describe the polyelectron state using [term symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol).

Comment: but aren't term symbols based on the non-interacting electrons approximation?

Comment: @Sparkler: no not really. They describe the overall properties e.g. the overall orbital angular momentum. We tend to rationalise this as so many electrons in the various $p$, $d$, etc orbitals, but at the end of the day it's only the totals that matter. Actually I suppose term symbols really only describe angular momentum, but what I'm getting at is they describe the atomic angular momentum without worrying about individual electrons.

Comment: `The radial part of the orbitals will be different for different central potentials` -- so the 1s orbital, for example, is not the same 1s orbital for different atomic numbers?

Comment: @Sparkler: yes! Basically, as you increase the atomic number the 1s orbital shrinks inwards.

Comment: you mentioned the Li case, which demonstrates that the actual degeneracy of orbitals is in fact not consistent with the central potential approximation. so going back to the original question, would it be safe to say that the energetic degeneracy in *real* polyelectronic atoms is different than in central potential model?

Comment: @Sparkler: I wasn't keen on the way you edited my answer, but I agree it's probably worth mentioning the things we chatted about. I have to go now but I'll look at editing my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Do you have any idea how good the approximation is? For example, if I wanted to calculate the energy stored in the bond between the two oxygen atoms in an oxygen molecule, how far would that be from the actual value? I mean, is it a percent or two, or tens of percent? Does it get significantly worse for more complex atoms?

Comment: @Luaan This is a big topic in [computational] physics -  quantum many-body systems. Even in the most simple three-body problem in **classical** physics, three point-masses interacting gravitationally, there are many unsolved issues. The intricacies of order and chaos that arise from these systems are studied every day by mathematicians, scientists, and engineers around the world.

Comment: @Luaan: I was doing this stuff in the mid-80s (30 years ago!!!) and my memories of it are a bit vague. In those days we'd start with an [HF-SCF calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) to get the central field approximation then a [CI calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_interaction) to include the effects of electron correlations. The CI would make an experimentally measurable difference i.e. to reproduce experimental results with experimental errorr you did need to include the correlations.

Comment: I'm curious though: do these multielectronic multidimensional wavefunctions still truly have the same _quantum number structure_ as though they were made by orbitals, that is, like in Helium, can all the steady state definite energy wavefunctions (6 dimensional) be categorized with 6 quantum numbers just as the hydrogen wavefunctions of that type can be categorized by 3? Or are there actually more quantum numbers?

Comment: Or is there a more complicated hierarchy of multidimensional steady state definite energy wavefunctions that defies such description? (But I still presume, a countable number of such wavefunctions only as it's still quantized, right?)

Answer (score 4):

Although John Rennie is right to remind us that when talking about orbitals for a multi-electron atom, it is only an approximation, I would like to point out that the source of the *exact* degeneracy of the (many-electron) atomic states, it is the isotropy of the atom in the absence of external polarizing fields. This makes the (total) angular momentum J and its projection m, exact quantum numbers, applicable to classification of atomic terms.