# Why do all atoms follow the same $n$ and $\ell$ quantization conditions as hydrogen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

The quantum state of an electron in a hydrogen atom is specified by 4 quantum numbers: $n$ , $\ell$, $m_\ell$, $m_s$ which can take the following values:
$$n =  1, 2, 3, ... $$
$$\ell = 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-1 $$
$$m_\ell =  -\ell , -(\ell-1), ... , (\ell-1), \ell$$
$$m_s = +\frac{1}{2} ,-\frac{1}{2} $$
If I'm not mistaken, the condition that specifies that specifies the highest $\ell$ value can be found when solving the radial Schrödinger equation. 
Therefore, why can we also apply the same rules for determining the electronic configuration of an atom with many electrons? Wouldn't the potential energy term in the radial equation be altered by the presence of all of the other electrons, hence resulting in a different relationship between $n$ and the highest possible value of $l$?

Comment: A possible answer is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238180/

Comment: Spherical symmetry and normal modes combined with representation of a basis of the rotation group in the appropriate Hilbert space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do non-hydrogen atomic orbitals have the same degeneracy structure as hydrogen orbitals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238180/)